# NumberPicker displaying formated strings dosen't show selected value

Tags: java, android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

So I load a list of objects successfully and format it like this.

```
  mNumberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
                        @Override
                        public String format(int value) {
                            String string = List.get(value);
                            return (string);
                        }
                    });
```

It works but i get a problem that i can't figure out.

- The selected item is invisible until i TOUCH THE PICKER but then it  stays visible until i click on the SELECTED ITEM.

Pickers I use when they are filled with numbers and I don't have to format does not have this problem.

Comment: have you found a solution for that?